# How to visualize time series using PCA?

Tags: time-series, python, pca, data-visualization, synthetic-data

I have two multivariate data sets comprised of 100s of time series, one is the actual recorded data set of time series and the other is a synthetically generated data set based on the recorded one.
The data set consists of 8 columns (DataFrame): 3 columns for the acceleration in $x$,$y$, and $z$ direction and 3 columns for the rotation in $x$, $y$, and $z$ direction and the target. The target would be the $Location$ (20 different locations), i.e. the current position. The last column would be the index that tells to which time series a row corresponds. So, the data set captures the trajectory of the same path traversed (100x traversed; 100 time series). How would you visualize the actual data set against the generated one to tell intuitively whether these are similar? I thought about PCA to reduce the dimension to 3 to plot the data but I am not quite sure to what data I should apply PCA. Should I gather from each run (time series) all rows corresponding to a $Location$ and then apply PCA to it and then take all rows for the same $Location$ of a $single$ run, transform them using PCA and plot it against the same run of the synthetically generated data set or how would you do that?